# Como importar para Json dados de uma tabela no Excel

Tags: javascript, html, json, microsoft-excel

Quero gerar gráficos com Chart.js e preciso importar dados de uma planilha do excel para json afim de elaborar o gráfico.

```
var data = {
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        **data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]**
    },
    {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        **data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]**
    }
]
```

};

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?

Comment: Não..até hoje esta pedente

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse link, era isso?... Inclusive era uma pergunta sua.
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122082/ferramenta-para-converter-excel-para-json

Comment: Alex, você resolveu o seu problema?

Comment: Não... até hoje esta pedente!!!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isto usando alguma ferarmenta online [como esta aqui](https://beautifytools.com/excel-to-json-converter.php), ou automatizar usando [esta biblioteca para Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-excel-to-json). Dá pra converter a tabela pra json de maneira bem simples:

```
var parser = new (require('simple-excel-to-json').XlsParser)();
var doc = parser.parseXls2Json('exemplo.xlsx'); // Nome do arquivo

console.log(doc[0]); // Planinlha já convertida para JSON
```